Has any TFR been issued due to “abnormally high pressure”?
TFR is supposed to be issued if the barometric pressure is more than 31.00”Hg as it is greater than altimeter adjustment range. Has this type of TFR been issued before within the U.S.?

I mean TFR is supposed to be issued if the pressure is more than 31.00"Hg to prohibit flight operation. And I was wondering if that would occur within the U.S. or not.

I see you are at KDAB where the pressure got up to the upper 30.40s at some point this past week.

There has been an episode of extreme cold in Alaska in February 1989. The pressure exceeded 31 inHg. According to the LA Times:

Barometric pressure, which had reached a North American record of 31.84 inches on Tuesday, was still so high in Alaska that the Federal Aviation Administration banned night and instrument flights because altimeters could not be accurately calibrated to give altitude readings.

That's not the pressure itself which is a problem, but the QNH that must be entered in the altimeter setting window, calculated by extrapolating this pressure to sea level (0.1 inHg added for each 100ft of altitude of the measurement location).
During this episode a C-130 crashed  at Fort Wainwright's Ladd Army Air Field, with a pressure of 30.79 inHg (I assume it's the QNH) just below the 31 inHg limit for altimeter setting. The cause was more the temperature (-52°C) and the icing fog.
QNH history at Fairbanks airport:



Source.
As confirmed by @Chris, at this time 14 CFR 91.114 didn't exist, so the TFR wasn't based on it. However the principle was written into the law in 1994, first as 91.92, then moved to 91.114 to be grouped with other TFR articles. The law justification included this 1989 event as well as the increasing possibility of such events in the next 10 years.
High pressure and low temperature are typical of Siberian climate, though the current world record for high pressure is 32.25 inHg (1089.1 hPa) at Tosontsengel in Mongolia on 29 December 2004.

"Some sites state this event actually caused the restriction to be added to the FAA regulations." These sites are correct. 91.114 was added in 1994 (initially as 91.92) and the FAA specifically cites the 1989 event as justification for the new regulation. (See 59 FR 17450).

@Chris: Thanks, that's a very useful information, added in my answer.
